# Install stickynotes error

Tags: stickynotes

After executing below command :

```
sudo snap install stickynotes
```

I got this error :

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/stickynotes: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
```

Is there anyone having the same issue before and has solved this issue?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu release?